# Is there any configuration necessary to use Hibernate Validation custom messages

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, hibernate-validator

I'm using the following class to validate my beans with Hibernate Validation.  It works great.  It's basically the listener found [here](http://agoncal.wordpress.com/2010/03/03/bean-validation-with-jpa-1-0/) for JPA 1, converted to use to validate beans in my Spring controllers.  I'm attempting to customize the messages returned.  [This](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/3.1.0/reference/en/html/validator-defineconstraints.html) and every other resource I can find say to just put a ValidationMessages.properties file in the Web-Inf directory.  This file is also included below.  This is not working.  Any suggestions?

```
public class BeanValidationTool {

    public void validate(Object entity) {
        TraversableResolver tr = new MyTraversableResolver();
        Validator validator = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory().usingContext().traversableResolver(tr).getValidator();
        final Set<ConstraintViolation<Object>> constraintViolations = validator.validate(entity);
        if (constraintViolations.size() > 0) {
          Set<ConstraintViolation<?>> propagatedViolations = new HashSet<ConstraintViolation<?>>(constraintViolations.size());
          Set<String> classNames = new HashSet<String>();
            for (ConstraintViolation<?> violation : constraintViolations) {
              propagatedViolations.add(violation);
              classNames.add(violation.getLeafBean().getClass().getName());
            }
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            builder.append("validation failed for classes ");
            builder.append(classNames);
            throw new ConstraintViolationException(builder.toString(), propagatedViolations);
        }
    }

    public class MyTraversableResolver  implements TraversableResolver {

        public boolean isReachable(Object traversableObject, Path.Node traversableProperty, Class<?> rootBeanType, Path pathToTraversableObject, ElementType elementType) {
            return traversableObject == null || Hibernate.isInitialized(traversableObject);
        }

        public boolean isCascadable(Object traversableObject, Path.Node traversableProperty, Class<?> rootBeanType, Path pathToTraversableObject, ElementType elementType) {
            return true;
        }
    }
  }`
```

> ValidationMessages.properties file

```
validator.min = must be greater than or equal to {value}

validator.notEmpty = This field can't be empty
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define messageSource in your application context:

```
<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource" abstract="false"
      scope="singleton" lazy-init="default">
    <property name="basename" value="ValidationMessages"/>
</bean>
```

Than you just use the bean to retrieve the messages:

```
@Autowired
private MessageSource messageSource;

public String getMessage(String messageName) {
    return messageSource.getMessage(messageName, null, null);
}
```

In order to access the beans in context you will have to do this as well:

```
@Component
public class BeanValidationTool{...
```

Comment: This is a great description of how to set up custom messages in Spring but, maybe my understanding is limited, I think that in order to customize Hibernate Validator messages specifically, that I should not have to use a bean.  Instead the values should be substituted automatically and be returned when the validate method is called.